# Ember render child template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to render a details view based on what gets clicked on the list view (parent/child view).
So I have nested route as below;

```
this.route('my-list', function() {
    this.route('my-details', {
        path: '/details'
    });
});
```

Also my child/details route looks like below

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params){
    var detailsUrl = "/myApp/json/" + params.myCode + "/details";
    var detailsRequest = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: detailsUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'id': params.Id
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                resolve(response);
            },
            error: function(reason) {
              reject(reason);
            }
        });
    });
    detailsRequest.then(function(response) {
        return response; // I do get the correct response here
    }, function(error) {
    });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    debugger;
    controller.set('model', model);
}
});
```

And my child/details controller looks like below

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['myCode','Id'],
    productCode: null
});
```

And my child template is as below; (I have a {{outlet}} in my parent/list template)

```
<p>Child details </p>
someId : {{model.someId}}
```

While I am able to make the AJAX call to 
"/myApp/json/" + params.myCode + "/details"
and get the response, it is not getting rendered to the child template

I noticed the setupController not getting called. Does it have to be manually called OR should it get called automatically (Do rememeber I am using a nested view)

Comment: thx..but i could not understand clearly when you say provide "reutrn" in before detailsRequest

Answer (score 0):

First mistake i see is that you're returning the result to the promise function not to the model

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

detailsRequest.then(function(response) {
    return response; // I do get the correct response here
}, function(error) {
});
```

Correct way should be

```
return detailsRequest.then(function(response) {
        return response; // I do get the correct response here
    }, function(error) {
```

Comment: Let's fix this and then move on, if issue does not get fixed. =)

Comment: Thx..I now see that the setupController is called and model is set with correct values...but the template is still not rdnering...Do I have to do anything special to render that ?

Comment: Well.. cant really tell what's the issue then. Post the result of your ajax request to question..

Comment: @testndtv why are you using views? They are are removed from Ember.

Comment: i am not using views (it is just a term to explain i have used here)

Comment: anyways post more info. about your outlet and json response.

Comment: But just to ask, is the above way the best practice OR correct approach to have parent/child kind of implementation & specifically the way I am getting the child details ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92491/discussion-between-kristjan-reinhold-and-testndtv).